# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'Adeleke'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I tried testing my php software with XAMMP (Local Host) but after hitting the URL, I kept getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'Adeleke'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I thought it was from xammp **PhpMyAdmin** so I installed Laragon and tried testing the software on it, below is what it shows

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'Adeleke'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\laragon\www\MyQueerDate\install\index.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\MyQueerDate\install\index.php(47): mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'Adeleke', 'Badvibe019!', 'Laragon.MySQL') #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\MyQueerDate\install\index.php on line 47
```

Here is the code on MyQueerDate\install\index.php on line 46 - 49:

```
if (!empty($_POST['install'])) {
   $con = mysqli_connect($_POST['sql_host'], $_POST['sql_user'], $_POST['sql_pass'], $_POST['sql_name']);
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       $ServerErrors[] = "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
```

I tried to check the output of the software and view the dashboard and the admin panel but it kept on showing;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'Adeleke'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\laragon\www\MyQueerDate\install\index.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\MyQueerDate\install\index.php(47): mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'Adeleke', 'Badvibe019!', 'Laragon.MySQL') #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\MyQueerDate\install\index.php on line 47
```

I tried it on cPanel and it works but I don't want to be testing programs on cPanel, I can't afford paying hosting fees for now and I want to try localhost.

Comment: You provide either the wrong username and or password.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check user and login permissions
   select user,host from mysql.user;
   If you are in this list, you can connect normally
2. Check whether the user name and password are correct
3. You can try to use mysql -uusername -ppassword to log in on the mysql server, you can better get the cause of the error, and then improve

Answer (score -1):

create a new user and use it to get access to your database.

Query:
create user 'user'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON urdatabase.* To 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Answer (score -1):

Had the same very issue; though i resolved by checking all Global privileges

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).